# The content of a HTML date input field is shifting to the left when I input data in it

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to fix this problem. In my HTML form I have 2 ´input[type="date"]` fields like this:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="advanced-search">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Dateiname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzer">
      <input type="date" placeholder="Erstelldatum">
      <input type="date" placeholder="Änderungsdatum">
      <textarea placeholder="Erste Zeile"></textarea>
      <select>
        <option disabled selected>Kategorie</option>
        <option>Rechnungen</option>
        <option>Notizen</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option disabled selected>Projekt</option>
      </select>
      <img id="advSearchSubmit" src="icons/search.png" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding SCSS:

```
.search-wrapper {
  position: fixed;

  .advanced-search {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: $accent-color;
    color: $font-color-secondary;
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="text"], input[type="date"], select, textarea {
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 110px;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 2px;
      background: $data-background-color;
      color: #555;
      border: 1px solid $background-color;
      outline-color: $main-color;
      font-size: 100%;
    }

    textarea {
      height: 2em;
      width: 41.2em;
    }
  }
}
```

As soon as I enter a date in the input field it gets shifted to the left and is not fully visible. Here is what it looks like when I don't have anything entered in the input field and when there is something entered:

[Date Input Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFhz7.jpg)

How do I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Create a demo of the current output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself. I just had to increase the `width` of the `input[type="date"]` field to at least `120px`

Answer (score 0):

**.search-wrapper and  .advanced-search** missing closing  braces
remove display none property if you are using it without js

```
.search-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
}
  .advanced-search {

    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: $accent-color;
    color: $font-color-secondary;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
    img {
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="text"], input[type="date"], select, textarea {
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 110px;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding:0px 4px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 2px;
      background: $data-background-color;
      color: #555;
      border: 1px solid $background-color;
      outline-color: $main-color;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    input[type="date"]{

    width:140px;    }

    textarea {
      height: 2em;
      width: 41.2em;
    }
```